# Most time/space efficient way to check if all elements in list of integers are 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

This is an implementation question for Python 2.7

Say I have a list of integers called `nums`, and I need to check if all values in `nums` are equal to zero. `nums` contains many elements (i.e. more than 10000), with many repeating values.

Using `all()`:

```
if all(n == 0 for n in set(nums)):  # I assume this conversion from list to set helps?
    # do something
```

Using set subtraction:

```
if set(nums) - {0} == set([]):
    # do something
```

Edit: better way to do the above approach, courtesy of user U9-Forward

```
if set(nums) == {0}:
    # do something
```

How do the time and space complexities compare for each of these approaches? Is there a more efficient way to check this?

Note: for this case, I am trying to avoid using numpy/pandas.

Comment: Second could be nicer: `set(nums)=={0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any set conversion of `nums` won't help as it will iterate the entire list:

```
if all(n == 0 for n in nums):
    # ...
```

is just fine as it stops at the first non-zero element, disregarding the remainder.

Asymptotically, all these approaches are linear with random data. 
Implementational details (no repeated function calls on the generator) makes `not any(nums)` even faster, but that relies on the absence of any other falsy elements but`0`, e.g. `''` or `None`.

Comment: You can get a x10 speedup by eliminating the explicit comparison and the generator.

Comment: How about a case in which nums contains both 0 (int) and 0.0 (float)? Would `not any(nums)` and `all(nums)` still work correctly?

Answer (score 2):

`not any(nums)` is probably the fastest because it will stop when/if it finds any non-zero element.

**Performance comparison:**

```
a = range(10000)
b = [0] * 10000
%timeit not any(a) # 72 ns, fastest for non-zero lists
%timeit not any(b) # 33 ns, fastest for zero lists
%timeit all(n == 0 for n in a) # 365 ns
%timeit all(n == 0 for n in b) # 350 µs
%timeit set(a)=={0} # 228 µs
%timeit set(b)=={0} # 58 µs
```

Comment: And so will `all`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl In fact, _your_ solution is about 10 times slower than mine - because of the generator.

Comment: That's a valid point, but it doesn't make your argument any more true.

Comment: I am not arguing _against_ `all`.

Comment: But you do so by by pointing out that `any` stops at the first non-zero element which does not differentiate it from `all`.

Comment: It does differentiate it from all set-based solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184254/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-dyz).

Comment: +1 Because you're timings look good. (I was running timings myself, but you beat me too it). But 'all()' doesn't provide a correct solution. all([0]) returns false where all elements are zero, true is correct. You can't just add a 'not' in front because all([0,1]) also returns false which is correct. If you think about it, you will realize 'all' is not the right test. All your other tests look good.

Comment: @jimhark You are right, the `all` solutions were incorrect. Which invalidates the original argument of @schwobaseggl .

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numpy, then `(np.array(nums) == 0).all()` should do it.

Comment: That's unlikely to help since the list needs to be read fully to just create the array.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @schwobaseggl's answer, second example could be even better:

```
if set(nums)=={0}:
    # do something
```